# Submit button with image background - CSS

Tags: css, image, background, submit

I can't figure out why my CSS won't work with my submit button.   Am I missing something?

```
.searchREG {
   width: 184px; 
   height:175px; 
   float:left; 
   background: url('/admin/img/search.png') no-repeat;
}

 .searchREG:hover {
   background-position: 0 -175px no-repeat; 
   cursor:pointer
 }


 <input class="searchREG" type="submit" value="submit">
```

Comment: What is not working? Can it be shown in a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/)? It will be much easier to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should see if there is not a problem with the url of your image. (what exactly does not work?)

Try remove the first slash in your image url. (encountered it once)

```
background: url('admin/img/search.png') no-repeat;
```